# How to take form name, from which, on submit, is call javascript function in this jscript function and then use name in same js function as variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to call same javascript function (chek() ) from three form's on onSubmit event and need to know which one form called this function. It is three buttons. How I can transfer name of form in javascript function chek(), which one is called on submit form, and then in javascript do something with name of form as variable. Example:

```
<form id="one" action="" method="post" onSubmit="chek();">
<input type="hiden" id="idfi11" name="idf1">
<input type="submit" id="idfi12"> value="B1" >

<form id="two" action="" method="post" onSubmit="chek();">
<input type="hiden" id="idfi21" name="idf1">
<input type="submit" id="idfi22"> value="B2" >

<form id="three" action="" method="post" onSubmit="chek();">
<input type="hiden" id="idfi31" name="idf1">
<input type="submit" id="idfi32"> value="B3" >
```

This is three buttons and depend of which one is click javascript chek() chek something and
count some result. Example javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chek()
{
var message1,message2,message3="";
var data="";
 ... count data string, and message1,message2, messag3....

 if (callname = form one) // here I need name of called form
    {
    alert("Message one :"+ message1);
    document.getElementById("idfi11").value = data;
    }
 if (callname = form two)
    {
    alert(Message two : + message2);
    document.getElementById("idfi21").value = data;
    }  
if (callname = form three)
    {alert("Message three :"+message3);document.getElementById("idfi22").value = data;}
return (true);
}
</script>
```

Thank You very much for reply...

Comment: Your forms don’t have a name, they have an id. And to access that, simply pass the element the function is called on as parameter to your function – `onSubmit="chek(this)"`.

Comment: If use jQuery, `.submit` will hold form element, that you can pass around. `$(this).attr('name')` will return that element name.

Comment: Thank You both. I m new and I not use yet jQueri.. @CBroe I have do this, and alert message for allert(vform) form is 'this' is [object] HTMLFormElement. And how get a variable of name or ID  of HTMLFormeElement ?

Comment: It is ok now and work super. I write alert as alert(vform.id); in js and this show ID of the form...

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

**HTML**

```
<form id="one" name="one" action="" method="post" onSubmit="chek(this);">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function chek(obj){
    alert(obj.id);// will give you ID of form
    alert(obj.name);// will give you NAME of form
}
```

Don't forget to add name attribute to form.

Answer (score 0):

I do this

```
<form id="one" action="" method="post" onSubmit="chek(this);">
...
```

Javascript

```
function chek(vforma)
{   
alert(vforma.id); // result= 'one'
...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript :

chek(this);

Jquery :

$(element).closest("form").attr("id");